# Why shuffling data gives significantly higher accuracy?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

In Tensorflow, I've wrote a big model for 2 image classes problem. My question is concerned with the following code snippet:

```
X, y, X_val, y_val = prepare_data()
probs = calc_probs(model, session, X)
accuracy = float(np.equal(np.argmax(probs, 1), np.argmax(y, 1)).sum()) / probs.shape[0]
loss = log_loss(y, probs)
```

X is an np.array of shape: (25000,244,244,3). That code results in accuracy=0.5834 (towards random accuracy) and loss=2.7106. But
when I shuffle the data, by adding these 3 lines after the first line:

```
sample_idx = random.sample(range(0, X.shape[0]), 25000)
X = X[sample_idx]
y = y[sample_idx]
```

, the results become convenient: accuracy=0.9933 and loss=0.0208.
Why shuffling data can give significantly higher accuracy ? or what can be a reason for that ?

The function calc_probs is mainly a run call:

```
probs = session.run(model.probs, feed_dict={model.X: X})
```

**Update:**
After hours of debugging, I figured out that evaluating a single image gives different result. For example, if you run the following line of code multiple times, you get a different result each time:

```
session.run(model.props, feed_dict={model.X: [X[20]])
```

My data is normally sorted, X contains class 1 samples first then class 2. And in calc_probs function, I run using each batch of the data sequentially. So, without shuffling, each run has data of a single class.
I've also noted that with shuffling, if batch size is very small, I get the random accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

There is some mathematical justification for this in the context of randomized Kaczmarz algorithm. Regular Kaczmarz algorithm is an old algorithm which can be seen as an non-shuffling SGD on a least squares problem, and there are guaranteed faster convergence rates that come out if you use randomization, follow references in http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~nickhar/W15/Lecture21Notes.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I know this and I agree with you. But my model is already trained I'm speaking about evaluating it here with shuffled vs. non-shuffled data. Sorry if that was not clear from the question.

Comment: Hm, your forward prop gives different result each time? That sounds kind of weird, what kind of your network are you using?

Comment: I use InceptionV3.

Comment: Is something funny going on with the batch normalization?